# Displaying Data's in between two dates from the database in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Displaying Data's in between two dates from the database in jdbc

**1. DAO**

```
 public int getdata(Date startDate,Date endDate) {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    int id = 0;

    try {

        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project.order WHERE
                        PO_Date >="+startDate+" AND PO_Date <= "+endDate+"");
        System.out.println("value of ps "+ps);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("value of rs "+rs);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("value of while loop "+rs.next());
            ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getDate(2));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(5));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(6));

            System.out.println("******************");

            Iterator<String> itr = arrlist.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(itr.next());

            }
        rs.close();
    } 
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
  }
}
```

---

**2. Controller**

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = null;

    String startDate=request.getParameter("StartDate");
    String endDate=request.getParameter("EndDate");

    Date utilDate1 = null;
    Date utilDate2 = null;
    try {
        utilDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(startDate);
        utilDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(endDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
    java.sql.Date sqlDate1 = new java.sql.Date(utilDate1.getTime());
    java.sql.Date sqlDate2 = new java.sql.Date(utilDate2.getTime());

    CountDTO countDTO = new CountDTO();
    countDTO.setStartDate(sqlDate1);
    countDTO.setEndDate(sqlDate2);

    CountService countService = new CountService();
    int ProductOrder = countService.getdata(countDTO);

    if (ProductOrder != 0) {
        requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("view/sucess.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
  }
}
```

---

**3. Service**

```
 public int getdata(CountDTO countDTO) {
    int i = 0;
    Date startDate = countDTO.getStartDate();
    Date endDate = countDTO.getEndDate();

    try {
        java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime());
        java.sql.Date sqlEndDate = new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime());
        CountDAO countDAO=new CountDAO();
        i = countDAO.getdata(sqlStartDate, sqlEndDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return i;
  }
}
```

---

I am trying the above code to display the data's in between the two dates StartDate and EndDate. But I am not getting the output.

**Console**

```
value of ps com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@15daccd: SELECT * FROM
  project.order WHERE PO_Date >=2016-01-02 AND PO_Date <= 2016-04-25
value of rs com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@7031d7
```

[image]

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen,@ SamGhatak,@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: When you run the query in your native database, do you get any results?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen iam getting the result when i enter manually in database

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen,@ SamGhatak,@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Your parametrized query is wrong, and you did not take my advice from the previous question.

Comment: Try this: `ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project.order WHERE PO_Date >= '2016-01-02' AND PO_Date <= '2016-04-25'");`

Comment: Try with Between clause i.e  PO_Date between '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'

Comment: @Deepanshu No, he should _not_ try this, it is vulnerable to SQL injection.  And the problem seems to be that he is not escaping his dates but rather concatenating them in a `String` (which is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM project.order po
 WHERE po.PO_Date IS NOT NULL
 AND TO_DATE(PO_Date, 'DD/MM/RRRR') >=
   TO_DATE('17/02/2015', 'DD/MM/RRRR')
 AND TO_DATE(PO_Date, 'DD/MM/RRRR') <=
   TO_DATE('20/06/2015', 'DD/MM/RRRR');
```

Comment: i want it in dynamically

Comment: @PopoFibo give me the solution

Comment: Write this in your `method`. And call this method by passing the `startDate` and `endDate` as parameter.